# Windows update to other computers on home network?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, home-networking, windows-10-v1703

My desktop PC is currently downloading a large update that I believe is called the *Windows 10 Creators Update*.

While I don't have a data cap, my internet speed is quite slow, so I am wondering - is there a way to get my other two Windows 10 machines (2 laptops) to use the same update that is currently downloading onto my desktop?  This is home network.  Desktop connected to router with network cable, the laptops with WiFi (but can be cable if required).

I am not downloading an ISO file (in hindsight that might have been an option I should have looked into first).  This is updating through the *Windows 10 Update Assistant* which just launched through Windows Update (Windows Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update).

Comment: 1703 isn't being pushed by Windows Update until after April 11th, Windows 10 has supported what you want though since it was released, have you enabled that function?  Sadly though, since your manually downloading the feature update, the windows update feature I described, can't be used.  I suggest cancelling the download and create the ISO instead and simply mounting it and launching the setup

Comment: @Ramhound is updating through Windows update still considered a manual update? I just opened Windows update and it told me this update was available, and to open the update assistant. I wasn't aware there was another way to do it.

Comment: No; your using the upgrade assistant; which means it's downloading the ISO as an ESD

Comment: Download the v1703 ISO and use the ISo to install the Windows10 Creators update on all PCs.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure how updates are delivered directly through Windows:

- Open up "Settings"
- Go to "Update & Security"
- Select "Windows Update"
- Under "Update settings", select "Advanced Options"
- Select "Choose how updates are delivered"
- Turn on "Updates from more than one place"
- Have "PCs on my local network" selected

This should allow your machines to download the update from other machines on your network as well as from the internet, which should definitely help speed up the overall download process for all of your machines.